# Pointer to function Kernighan book

Tags: c

my post is code of book.

```
void qsort(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *));  
/*Why it can be without name of pointer "comp"? like this: */
void qsort(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*)(void *, void *)); */

main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    int nlines; 
    int numeric =0; 
    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-n") == 0) 
    numeric = 1; 
    if ((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0) 
    { 
        qsort((void **) lineptr, 0, nlines-1, (int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)); 
        writelines(lineptr, nlines); 
        return 0; 
    } 
    else  ................
}
```

Why not like `(int (*comp)(void*,void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)` in main? 
And there question in code comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qsort` is being passed a pointer to a function.  The function is either `numcmp` or `strcmp` based on the value of `numeric`.  That function pointer is being cast to the type that `qsort` likes.  On this line

```
    (int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));
```

the `(int (*)(void *,void *))` is a cast.  When you are casting you don't specify a variable name.  For example, if you were casting an `int` to a `float` you would do:

```
int a = 5;
float b = (float)a;
```

you wouldn't use a name:

```
float b = (float somename)a;  /* invalid -- names are not used in type casting */
```

Comment: "That function pointer is being cast to the type that qsort likes." How?

Comment: I understood ternary operator. Question is not aboutit. What means cast to the type that qaort likes?

Comment: Sorry but where there is casting in qsort example?

Comment: @user2377214: If you see a type in parentheses, then that is a cast.  In this case `(int (*)(void *,void *))` is the cast.

Comment: Why  (int (*)(void *,void *)) is a cast? I thought it is pointer to int.

Comment: @user2377214: it is a cast to a pointer to a function that takes two void pointers as parameters and returns an int.

Comment: You answered in post. I was late.

Comment: int (*)(void *,void *) and (int (*)(void *,void *)) are not same?
Fitst is pointer to int but second is cast to pointer?
Is code below correct?
int (*)(void*,void*)(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)
instead of (int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)

Comment: @user2377214: You have to use the parentheses to make it a cast.